# How to use variable in another method?

Tags: java, android

I have basic problem with variable int myInt. In void aktualizujRynek() I assign value 2 for myInt. In void setImage(), variable has value 0 , not 2. Why?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int myInt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

aktualizujRynek();
setImage();

}


public void aktualizujRynek(){
final Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
myInt = 2;
});
thread1.start();
}


public void setImage(){
if (myInt ==2){  
//do something
}
}


}
```

Comment: It's not clear what's you wana achieve... At The time when you use variable it has value 0. If you wana use value after thread ends you should use callback. AsyncTask has it already moreover it's called back on ui thread... And obviously waiting for thread end inside onCreate is a terrible idea...

Comment: So I can't access myInt in thread?

Comment: Question is when in the time of execution of another thread you wana access it in current thread... You need to somehow inform current thread from another thread when variable had changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override `run()` method and put your code inside this method. Call `setImage()` from `run()` to get the proper result.

**Try this:**

```
public void aktualizujRynek(){
    final Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myInt  = 2;
            setImage();
        }
    });

    thread1.start();
}
```

Hope this will work~

Comment: Thanks Ferdous Ahamed! But still myInt is 0 when I use it in void setImage().

Comment: Because your setImage() get called before invoking run() method where you are changing myInt to 2. You have to call setImage() from run() to get proper result. See my updated answer

Comment: Happy to know. If my answer helps please mark it as accepted answer and give an upvote if possible. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

I want to set my image using voidsetImage(), when 2 conditions will be fulfilled ,if (myInt1 == 2  && myInt2 == 3). But when I use myInt1 and myInt2 in void setImage they have value 0 although I assigned values 2 and 3.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int myInt1;
int myInt2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

aktualizujRynek();
aktualizujPark();
setImage();

}


public void aktualizujRynek(){
final Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myInt1  = 2; // in my real code i take this value from HTTP response

    }
});

thread1.start();
}

public void aktualizujPark(){
final Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myInt2  = 3; // in my real code i take this value from HTTP response

    }
});

thread2.start();
}


public void setImage(){
if (myInt1 == 2  && myInt2 == 3){  
//do something
}
}


}
```

Comment: @FerdousAhamed do you know how to do it?